# eye detection giving some extra rectangle in OpenCV in python code

Tags: python, opencv

```
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    print("Found {0} eyes!".format(len(eyes)))
    for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)
```

Hi,
I am using OpenCV in python 3.
NOTE : I have 3 faces

but in the above code it's detected some extra eyes as rectangle

The output of the code returns extra eyes(only 1st output is correct) as below :-
Found 2 eyes!
Found 3 eyes!
Found 3 eyes!

Can anyone check the code, what's wrong here ????

Comment: [detectMultiScale](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale) Looking at the docs for detectMultiScale function, you can increase variables such as minNeighbors to make it so that you don't get false positives. It's a fine balance though.

Comment: which kind of algorithm you are using? You cant except to find all eyes for any types of algorithm. Many reasons not to find all.

Comment: Thank you all of you for your time. Now it's working, after the below change :                        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_color, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=5)

Answer (score 1):

**Try using this.**

```
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_color, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)
    print("Found {0} eyes!".format(len(eyes)))
    for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. In fact the below works perfect for me.                                                    
 eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_color, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=5)

Comment: eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_color, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=5)